# Подскажите идею как реализовать "описание фотографий"?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть большая галерея фотографий, сделана таким образом:

[image]

scandir возвращает массив все прекрасно парсится и отображается. Только вот теперь нужно к каждой фотографии привязать описание, и к каждой папке более подробное имя, т.е. скажем:

```
kitchens -> Кухни для детей
   ferrero -> Ferrero De Legno 2013
     day_n_night -> Коллекция День и Ночь
              00.png -> Оригинальное решение для детей от 5 до 10 лет.
```

Менять структуру совсем не хочется, база не используется :(
Подскажите идею как привязать "данные" к файлам?

1. Я придумал в корне каждой папки повесить что то вроде _details.php где будет массив сопоставления имён файлов\папок с "человеческим" текстом
2. Хранить в EXIF файла все "человеческие" название директорий к нему и собственно само описание
3. ...ваш вариант реализации?

Comment: Создавать php-конфиги в данном случае смысла нет - наполнение по времени будет занимать не меньше, чем если бы просто вручную создавались статичные html-файлы. EXIF - в целом неплохой вариант, но считывать его излишне ресурсоемко. Первая мысль, которая может придти для решения задачи - просто создание одноименных с файлами\папками текстовых файлов с нужным текстом в виде содержания - просто, быстро реализуется, легко изменять.

Comment: Больше никто не хочет ничего советовать, сделайте ответом -- я приму!

Comment: Последний вариант от @Равнодушный, только немного изменить: создать аналогичную структуру каталогов в другой папке (уровнем выше) и в ней держать **одноименные** файлы с описанием.

Тогда при работе с путями имея путь `./photos/kitchens/ferrero/day_n_night/00.png` доступ к описанию получаете просто подменой пути `./descr/kitchens/ferrero/day_n_night/00.png`

Можно и расширение менять :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему вы не хотите **теперь** использовать базу? Если у вас просто нет желания запускать отдельный сервис, возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону [SQLite](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite).

На PHP с ней довольно [просто работать](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sqlite.php), а удобство и гибкость имеет почти такую же, как и MySQL

Comment: Я как раз и рассматриваю варианты, может так и придется привязать базу.